# Is it possible for Matlab to read and decode an mp3 file?

Tags: audio, music, audio-processing, mp3

I have run the following Matlab code and I got a signal as shown in the Figure below.

```
[y, fs] = audioread(mp3file);
y1 = y(:,1);
y2 = y(:,2);
dt = 1/fs;
t1 = 0:dt:(length(y1)*dt)-dt;
t2 = 0:dt:(length(y2)*dt)-dt;
plot(t1,y1);  
hold on
plot(t2,y2);
```

[image: Signal]

Is this a signal generate from a raw mp3 file or it is generated from a Matlab-decoded-mp3 file (which means Matlab has internally decoded the mp3 file)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a signal generate from a raw mp3 file or it is generated from a Matlab-decoded-mp3 file

The latter. $audioread()$ reads the raw MP3 bit stream, decodes it, and returns the decoded audio data as PCM data. If you want the raw bit stream use $fread()$ instead.